# Why Doesn't My plist file work?

Tags: applescript

I put this plist file in the launchAgent folder on my iMac (running High Sierra) and then loaded it using

```
launchctl load  markJunkRead.plist
```

and it loads fine.  But it never fires (it supposed to every 5 minutes).  I tried putting a log file output and it never wrote anything to the log file.  I've rebooted my computer as well.  Is there something I'm missing here?  I'd appreciate any help on this.  Thanks

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
  <string>org.example.Mail.Clean</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/me/Library/Application\ Scripts/com.apple.mail/markJunkRead.scpt</string>
</array>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>300</integer>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Try using `/usr/bin/osascript` in place of just `osascript`.

Comment: Which folder did you put it in (i.e. /Library/LaunchDaemons,  /Library/LaunchAgents, or /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents), and what user did you load it as? The reason I'm asking is I'm pretty sure osascript will have trouble running as root independent of a user login session, and other users won't be able to read /Users/me/Library/ or anything in it.

Comment: Library/LaunchAgents is the folder all the launch agents are in. And the Library is under the user (which I called 'me')...if I go to the file and view info, that is the location of the file

Comment: user3439894, I'll make change now and see if this works...yes, that is where osascript is located in my system

Comment: a little progress..seems its now finding the osacript, but getting this error in my log file...does this mean it can't find my scpt file?
osascript: /Users/me/Library/Application\ Scripts/com.apple.mail/markJunkRead.scpt: No such file or directory

Comment: Remove the backslash in `.../Application\ Scripts/...` -- that's needed at the command line, but not here.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and user3439894...got it working with your help